# Nested List toolbar

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2, nested-lists

I am creating a nested list and setting the BackText on item tap using "setBackText()". That works fine.
But at the same time, I want the title of the toolbar to be set as well.

The code:

```
onItemTap : function(nestedList, list, index, node, record, e) {
                        var partsOfStr = record.get('text').split(';');
                        val = partsOfStr[2];
                        currDocument = val;
                        Ext.getCmp('nestedList').setTitle('HII');
                        Ext.getCmp('nestedList').setBackText(currDocument);

                    },
```

does not seem to be working for me.

Any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No error on the console. If I use Ext.getCmp('nestedList').getTitle();, i get the correct output, but the setTitle just doesn seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`updateTitleText` is *by default* set to `true` for `nestedlist`, so if you are using a `data` store to set the data for your `nestedlist`, your `title` will always be set according to which category of data you are selecting.

So, set

```
updateTitleText: false
```

and then try to set the `title` dynamically like this,

```
Ext.getCmp('nestedList').setTitle('HII');
```

Comment: The "updateTitleText: false" worked. Its not updating the title now, but the setTitle is still not working.